# What is the intuitive meaning of P(A,B|C)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, graphical-model

I have come across graphical models where we have a node C that is dependent on both A and B. For example a node C with incoming arrows from A and B.

In this case I know the intuition behind writing P(C|A,B) which means we are referring to the distribution of C given a particular value for A and a value for B.

However I have come across expression like P(A,B|C). What is the intuition here and how does the graphical model look like in this case?

Are we thinking of a node C which is generating both A and B? If yes does this expression indicate the joint distribution of A and B given that we know a value for C is given?

Comment: Conditional probability does not suggest causation.  So $P(A, B \mid C)$ is  $\dfrac{P(C \mid A,B) P(A,B)}{P(C)}$ which is $\dfrac{P(C \mid A,B) P(A,B)}{P(C \mid A,B) P(A,B)+P(C \mid A,B^c) P(A,B^c)+P(C \mid A^c,B) P(A^c,B)+P(C \mid A^c,B^c) P(A^c,B^c)}$ and if $A$ and $B$ are unconditionally independent then you have $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ etc.